# How does this circuit work? How can I analyse this circuit? 10 by 10 reaction game circuit

Tags: analysis, diagram

I built a project with the help of a breadboard diagram. Now I want to understand what this circuit does. How does this circuit work? I am looking for an analysis of this circuit diagram.

[image: Circuit picture]

Comment: Maybe this page will help: https://www.elprocus.com/ic-4017-pin-configuration-application/

Comment: Obiick - Hi, What have you done on this so far, to try to solve your own question? Did you download the datasheets for the two ICs and review the components connected directly to each IC, to understand how each of those "blocks" works? In other words, to avoid people repeating things you already know, please explain exactly where you are stuck, so readers can focus their answers there. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Sam, I am pretty new in these thing. I just wanted to know how this circuit is working. How its making the 10 by 10 reaction game work.

Comment: Hello EricR, thanks I will check on this page

Comment: @Obiick - Hi, "*I just wanted to know how this circuit is working.*" Stack Exchange has different rules to typical internet forums. Please familiarise yourself with the [tour] & [help] for more details. In the help center article "[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)" it explains, among other things: "*Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers [...]*" i.e. people asking questions are expected to research first. TY

Comment: Hint: The circuit is basically two separate parts, conveniently divided by a dotted line on the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

IC1 is an *astable multivibrator*, producing a 26.6 Hz square wave on its pin 3, with approximately 60% duty cycle.  It's a classic 555 circuit, and you can read more about how this works and the frequency calculation at [Wikipedia page about the 555 timer chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Astable)

That will flash the LED L1, but probably too fast to see.

When S1 is pressed, this signal is applied to the clock input of the counter IC2.  This is a [CD4017 *decade counter*](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf).  This counts input pulses and makes one of its outputs high, thus lighting one of the LEDs on the right, L2 to L11.  When it gets to 9, it goes back to 0.

It will behave somewhat as an electronic random number generator, choosing to light one of the LEDs depending on how long you press the switch for.

Just for completeness: R1, R2, C1 control the frequency and the duty cycle; C2, C3 decoupling; R3, R5 LED current limiting; R4 pull-down; Diagram wrongly says 4017 is a "BCD counter", but actually it's a *decade counter*.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. I will save this on my note for my study about this circuit.